# In Magento 2.2 how to add sample customer attribute?

Tags: customer-attribute, magento2.2

How can I add customer attribute in **Magento 2.2**?

Please help me in frontend and backend step wise step

if anybody have solution please share it

Answer (score 0):

Use "Manage Customer Attributes" extension. It is free. You can get it from the following URL.

[Manage Customer Attributes Magento 2](https://marketplace.magento.com/clarion-customer-attribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a module, but this would get you going as far as the install script goes for a customer attribute called `sample_attribute`. Make sure to substitute `VendorName` and `ModuleName` with your vendor and module names respectively:

#### File: app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Class InstallData
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Config $eavConfig,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Install Data
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $this->addCustomerAttributes($setup);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Add Customer Attributes
     *
     * @param $setup
     */
    private function addCustomerAttributes(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $customerAttributes = [
            'sample_attribute' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 100,
                    'system' => false,
                    'position' => 1000,
                ],
                'used_in_forms' => [
                    'adminhtml_customer',
                    'adminhtml_checkout',
                    'customer_account_create',
                    'customer_account_edit',
                    'checkout_register',
                ]
            ],
        ];

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set $attributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeSetGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        foreach ($customerAttributes as $attributeCode => $attributeData) {
            // Create Attribute
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, $attributeData['properties']);

            // Add Attribute to Set, Group, and Forms
            $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
            $attribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeSetGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => $attributeData['used_in_forms']
            ]);

            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```